# Match Complete word in string

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vb-like-operator

I have the  below code which populates an offset cell with service should the criteria match. However at  this stage, it operates on the basis  that should  the string appear within a cell, it will apply the value  rather than the word being a complete word. For example I have "Visit" within my criteria and "Vistor" (within a cell) will comply within my code when it shouldn't. Please can someone assist?

```
Option Compare Text
Sub CHECK_CELL_VALUES()
    Dim LASTROW As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Sheet1
        LASTROW = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row


            For i = 2 To LASTROW
                If Cells(i, 7).Value Like "*Service*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "*Servicing*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Labour*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Job*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Hire*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Visit*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Scaffold*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Contract*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Hour*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Month*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Quarter*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Day*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Maintenance*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Repair*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Survey*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Training*" _
                Or Cells(i, 7).Value Like "* Calibration*" _
                Then Cells(i, 7).Offset(0, 46).Value = "Service"
                Debug.Print Cells(i, 7).Address
            Next i

        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not add a space after Visit? So "* Visit *"

Comment: I also endorse @Trum suggestion that if you want to match such situation keep your criteria word surrounded by a space like " Visit "

Comment: Hi, thanks and sorry for the stupidity

Comment: @Trum  The use of space alone to define a word causes an issue if the word is at the beginning or end of a line; or if the word is "ended" with an apostrophe or quote mark.  That may not be an issue for the original poster.  But, in general, one could test for any non-word character, or the beginning or end of the string, in order to define a word.  This can be done with "straight VBA", and is also easily done using Regular Expressions which has a word boundary token.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do this is:
a) to add a space before and after the string to be searched
b) search for the string with a space added before and after.
here's an example that searches for the word VISIT
and it would match
"VISIT"
"A VISIT"
"VISIT SOMETHING"
but will exclude
"VISITOR"

```
InStr(1, " " & UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)) & " ", " VISIT ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this:

```
If Cells(i, 7).Value Like "*Service*"
```

to this:

```
If InStr(Cells(i,7).Value,"Service") > 0
```

And so on and so forth - this will match the entire string `"Service"` More info on `InStr` can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

Comment: Your code will still find the fragment within a larger word.  e.g. `Instr("Visitor","Visit")` will return a value > 0.